# How to release objects? [Java-GNOME]

Tags: java, gnome

how do i release objects in java-gnome library?
first, i give an example...

```
package gui;

import org.gnome.gdk.Event;
import org.gnome.gtk.Button;
import org.gnome.gtk.Widget;
import org.gnome.gtk.Window;

public class A extends Window implements Window.DeleteEvent
{
    private Button b;

    public A()
    {
        this.b = new Button();
    }

    public boolean onDeleteEvent(Widget w, Event e)
    {
        this.b.destroy();
        this.destroy();
        this.release();
        return false;
    }
}
```

should i use destroy and release functions like i do at this code?
how to i finally release the objects?

java-gnome api website:
http://java-gnome.sourceforge.net/4.0/doc/api/index.html?org/gnome/pango/package-summary.html

its free open source, if u can check it for me:
http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/sources/java-gnome/4.0/

download the file: "java-gnome-4.0.19.tar.gz"
thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on this link: http://java-gnome.sourceforge.net/doc/api/4.1/org/gnome/gtk/Widget.html#destroy%28%29

It seems it will. Of course, like the text in italics says, it may not remove all references to the object in *java* just the *GObject* system. But otherwise, this looks correct. Once your reference to this goes out of scope, it should be completely dereferenced, along with all children you may have skipped.

I would also recommend if you are destroying a window with lots of children, and you plan on destroying every single one of them, call this.hide() as your first step in the onDeleteEvent.
See: http://java-gnome.sourceforge.net/doc/api/4.1/org/gnome/gtk/Window.html

After reading through the docs looking for `release()`, I couldn't find it listed anywhere but in org.gnome.glib.Object, but there are not any actual direct methods from Object. I would recommend against using it.